# Loop not running completely on iPad (Fine on simulator)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an ARC based project. I am obtaining text from a large text file and need to remove white spaces or newline characters from it. The following code works fine on the simulator but crashes on an iPad and doesn't run completely (this may be a memory issues). For example if the loop needs to be run 2000 times, it crashes after running 1800 times on iPad.

```
- (BOOL)formatTheText {
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:_textFileURL
                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                            error:NULL];

NSRange paraRange = {0,1};
NSString *modifiedContent = @"";
BOOL previousLineWasEmpty = NO;
int lineNumber = 0;

while (paraRange.location < [content length]) {

    NSRange currentParaRange = [content paragraphRangeForRange:paraRange];
    NSString *paragraph = [content substringWithRange:currentParaRange];
    NSCharacterSet *newLineSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];

    NSArray *array = [paragraph componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newLineSet];
    NSString *currentParagraph = @"";

    for (NSString *line in array) {
        currentParagraph = [currentParagraph stringByAppendingString:line];
    }

    // Add a space when combining two lines
    modifiedContent = [modifiedContent stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ",currentParagraph];
    paraRange.location += currentParaRange.length;

    if ([currentParagraph length] == 0) {

        // If previous line was empty just add a new line character
        if (previousLineWasEmpty) {
            modifiedContent = [modifiedContent stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];

        } else {
            // Add two lines for the start of a new paragraph
            modifiedContent = [modifiedContent stringByAppendingString:@"\n\n"];
        }
        previousLineWasEmpty = YES;

    } else {
        previousLineWasEmpty = NO;
    }
    lineNumber++;
}
self.cleanedString = modifiedContent;
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Closes down the app and goes back to main menu.

Comment: Have you looked at the crash logs on your device?

Comment: Am viewing in xcode... Nothing appears because loop has not ended completely

Comment: Shove a breakpoint in at the beginning of the loop and just step through.

Comment: Are you using the same text file for both simulator and real device?

Comment: Yup using same file and I have found the solution :) I placed all the code inside while loop in autoreleasepool and loop is running completely on iPad without any crashes. Dont know the consequences though :p

Comment: Did your AppDelegate enter in `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` (do a `NSLog` in it, or a BreakPoint) ? This could be indeed the issue...

Comment: Yes memory warning showed when running the app on iPad. What could be the issue?